# Can't import PouchDB into Angular 5.2.0 application

Tags: angular, typescript, import, pouchdb

I'm trying to import PouchDB into my Angular application. I've tested differents import methods :

```js
import PouchDB from 'pouchdb';
import * as PouchDB from 'pouchdb';
```

I am using it like below into a service :

```js
database: PouchDB.Database = new PouchDB(DATABASE_URL);
```

---

If I do : `import PouchDB from 'pouchdb'`, I get the following error message :

> src/app/core/pouchdb/pouchdb.service.ts(3,8): error TS1192: Module '"{PATH_OF_PROJECT}/node_modules/@types/pouchdb/index"' has no default export.

If I do : `import * as PouchDB from 'pouchdb'`, I get the following error message :

> ERROR TypeError: PouchDB is not a constructor at new PouchDBService

---

Here are the versions of the different packages :

- PouchDB : 6.4.3
- @types/pouchdb : 6.3.2
- Angular packages : 5.2.0
- @angular/cli : 1.7.4

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: what typescript version are you using?
I could not reproduce the issue -> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-j8dk8h

Comment: I'm using typescript 2.5.3.
The only difference is that you use version 5.2.8 of Angular packages

Comment: I changed the stackblitz to use 5.2.0 and typescript 2.5.3 (although I can't verify if it really uses 2.5.3) and it still works.
have you recently updated some packages?
Sometimes it helps to just delete the whole `node_modules` folder and run `npm install` again

Comment: It's a new project so i didn't updated packages. I've already done the reinstallation of all node_modules.

Comment: don't put your answer in the question--post it as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 7):

Add `"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true` in the `compilerOptions` section of your ***tsconfig.json***

and use

```js
import PouchDB from 'pouchdb';
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. But I solved it by adding the PouchDb cdn to my index.html page

```
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/pouchdb/6.4.3/pouchdb.min.js"></script>
```

And then after I used it in my code like this

```
declare const  PouchDB;

const _DB_ = new PouchDB('dbname');
```